# Where to find/how to install libclang-*.so.1 on CentOS?

Tags: centos, clang

I am trying to find a library of `libclang-*.so.1` on centOS, but didn't find it anywhere. I have already installed `clang`. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219158/how-to-install-clang-and-llvm-3-9-on-centos-7/48103599 Read the answers and comments.

Comment: @ChanganAuto None of this works. Could you point out which solution works on your end?

Comment: Can't test it. But this should be up-to-date:            https://developers.redhat.com/HW/ClangLLVM-RHEL-7#enable_necessary_software_repositories

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is no mention on `libclang` in the given link. Maybe I missed sth?

Comment: It's not individually installed, it's part of a package. That's the point of the last links and all the others.